# Is there a free web app/service to plot data with a nonlinear X axis?

Tags: webapp-rec

Over on [Travel SE](https://travel.stackexchange.com/) our member Roflcopter has been working on [some tools to compliment the site via its API](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/420/do-we-need-tools-to-make-our-site-better).

But we don't yet have a nice plot of our number of views and users over time because the sample times (the X-axis) is a bit random rather than constant and we don't know a tool to plot it.

I thought there might be a web app like WolframAlpha that did plots as one of its services or as its only service.

**Is there a web app that could plot our `CSV` data in a nice graph without requiring a constant X-axis?**

For bonus points it would be nice to overlay both stats on a single graph.

Comment: Is it normal to downvote and closevote on this Stack Exchange without giving reasons? On most sites it's considered polite to leave constructive comments along with such actions.

Comment: IBM's [Many Eyes](http://www-958.ibm.com/software/data/cognos/manyeyes/) looks like a good contender but I can't figure out how to get the x-axis to work with dates or timestamps.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha has just launched a "Pro" variant which allows uploading and inputting data, including in CSV format. But so far I haven't been able to get it to plot the data in my CVS file. (I ended up writing a JavaScript tool to plot the data using Google Charts' "Annotated Timeline".)